# Optimal way to store units of measure for Stock items

Tags: database, database-design, oop, schema

Assuming a schema structure as such.

```
-----------------------------------------
Stock (ID, Description, blah blah)
-----------------------------------------
StockBarcode (ID, StockID, Barcode, Price, blah blah)
-----------------------------------------
```

What is the optimal way of storing units of measure for your stock items? Given that the StockBarcode Price may be for 1 item, for 10 Items, for 10 grams or for 10 pounds?

Stock to StockBarcode is a one to many relationship. (Although Im sure you didnt need me telling you that)

Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far. Just too elaborate a barcode would be specific to a UOM as you don’t want to prompt your user to enter a UOM at the time of entry. (Besides you dont need 2 since different UOM should have different barcodes) 
As for using the SKU not sure that would work. Imagine a scenario where you receive a packet of 50 pencils, all the pencils would contain the same SKU but you might sell them individually and as packs of 5. (It only works your way if your supplier provides them in the various QTYs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be adding `Qty` and `UOMID` columns to the StockBarcode table and then a new table like

```
StockUOM (ID, Description)
```

Comment: This was along the lines of what I was thinking.

Comment: +1 I would also consider adding a conversion factor to the StockUOM table, so that (for example) Kilogrammes could be converted to grammes by multiplying by 1000, or packs of 5 converted to singles by multiplying by 5. (Obviously, grammes could not be converted to packs of 5!)

Answer (score 4):

You might think about putting an additional UOM column on ALL tables where Qty fields are and additional Currency column on all money columns.

ALL entry screens should ask Qty and UOM.

> Item table - add Inventory/Stocking UOM, Purchasing/Receive UOM,
>   Pricing UOM, Shipping/Send UOM, Production UOM, Component UOM columns
>
> new UOM table - ID, Abbrev., Description, RegionID, UOMTypeID
>
> new UOMRegion table - ID, Code, Description   (example data - 1, UK,
>   United Kingdom;
>                     2, US, United States;
>                     3, INT, International)
>
> new UOMType table - ID, Code, Description, DefaultUOMID    (example
>   data - 1, V, Volume, 15;
>                      2, A, Area, 45;
>                      3, W, Weight, 32;
>                      etc.)
>
> new UOMConversionFactor table - ID, FromUOMID, ToUOMID,
>   ConversionFactor    (example data - 1, 1, 1,  1;
>                      2, 1, 3,  0.026021066655565;
>                      3, 3, 1, 38.430399999999000)
>
> (notes - Conversion from UOM to same UOM is 1. May put in table or
>   not.
>               Each record I usually have an implied column FromQty which is always 1.
>               Make sure ConversionFactor allows for HUGE numbers so final numbers turn out more accurate when large Qty are involved)

Thoughts - 1) some UOM are not specific enough such as "barrel" (there is a US dry goods barrel, a US barrel for cranberries,  U.S. fluid barrel, U.K. a beer barrel, US beer barrel, oil barrel, etc.), 2) UOM is impacted by region if you are worrying about an international application (ie. a US cup is different from UK cup that is different than the international cup), 3) I can get a receive a cartoon of item X, store it in pallets, and ship it in eaches. 4) "kit" or "build" items can be raw materials in UOM plus various components in different UOM that ultimately results in a final product in a different UOM.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your stock table correctly, it consists of the products that you are stocking to sell.

One option to consider is that instead of stock data maybe you should consider keeping the data based on what in stock keeping parlance, is referred to as [SKU (stock keeping unit) Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stock-keeping_unit).

Each SKU itself can be made of more than 1 item but as it cannot be sold that way, you dont have to concern yourself with those details in most scenarios. Details like price etc are all properties that are then associated with the SKU.

Eg: If a product say beer can be sold individually / 6 pack / 12 pack then it has 3 SKU's associated with it.

Then you have relationships :

```
Products --> SKU's which is 1:many
```

`SKU      --> StockBarCode which is 1:1` (assuming you have the same bar code for all the units of the same SKU - if not then it can be 1: Many as well)

Comment: @Maxim Gershkovich - I see the point you are trying to make in your comment above and its a valid one. Thinking a bit more on it though, SKU would be defined based on how you sell your products rather than how you get them from suppliers. However, i still see your point that if the the POS has an option to break open a packet of 5 pencils and sell it individually instead, that would mean updating the sku information everytime he does something like that, which would be cumbersome! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a unique StockBarcode for every UOM? For example, is there a barcode for grams, a barcode for pounds and a barcode for individual items? If so, Andrew's solution will work.

If not, you will need to create another table that contains the StockID, Qty and UOMID's.

```
StockUOM (ID, Description)

StockCount (ID, StockID, UOMID, Qty)
```

When you scan the barcode, you will need to enter in what UOM you are scanning for. Then the software can update the StockCount table based on item scanned. This could be a good fallback in case your items don't have more than one barcode, and you are stocking more than one UOM (common).